How can I create an object with the value the result from an api call?
Good evening,
I am currently trying to create an object that will contain:
{
  "acct_123": [
   // result from calling stripe api 
  ],
  "acct_456": [
   // result from calling stripe api 
  ]
}

The parameter of my function is the list of stripeIds: ['acct_123', 'acct_456']
I tried this:
const fetchList = async (id: string) => {
    const resp = await stripe.accounts.listExternalAccounts(
        id,
        { object: "bank_account" },
        { apiKey }
     )
    return resp.data;
 }

let bankAccoutFetchPromises: any = [];
let obj;
stripeConnectAccountIds.map(async (id: string) => {
      const bankAccountList = await stripe.accounts.listExternalAccounts(
        id,
        { object: "bank_account" },
        { apiKey }
      );
      obj[id] = bankAccountList.data;
      bankAccoutFetchPromises.push(bankAccountList.data);


 });
Promise.all(bankAccoutFetchPromises);

Unfortunately this call only fetch the data for the first element in the array. :|
Can you please help me with setting object key the id and the value the result from fetchList(id)?
Thanks! :)

your fetch list function
   const fetchList = async (id) =>
     (await stripe.accounts.listExternalAccounts(
       id, { object: "bank_account" })).data;

map ids to promises
let fetchPromises = stripeAccountIds.map(id =>
  fetchList(id).then(data => ({ id, data })));

once all promises resolve results will be an array of ids and corresponding data
  const results = await Promise.all(fetchPromises);

construct the result object
   let resultObject = results.reduce((acc, { id, data }) =>
           ({ ...acc, [id]: data }), {});

putting it all together.
const stripe = require('stripe')('your_stripe_secret_key');

const fetchList = async (id) =>
    (await stripe.accounts.listExternalAccounts(id, { object: "bank_account" })).data;

async function fetchAllAccounts(stripeAccountIds) {
    let fetchPromises = stripeAccountIds.map(id =>
        fetchList(id).then(data => ({ id, data }))
    );

    const results = await Promise.all(fetchPromises);

    let resultObject = results.reduce((acc, { id, data }) =>
        ({ ...acc, [id]: data }), {}
    );

    return resultObject;
}

// Example usage:
const stripeConnectAccountIds = ['acct_123', 'acct_456'];
fetchAllAccounts(stripeConnectAccountIds).then(result => console.log(result));

